# Two animations using css, javascript, two buttons onclick()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, svg

I want to create two animations in css. In my project, I use two button, one object. I care, that the first button is being clicked, the first animation on the object is being run.

I know, what I should do, when I have one button and one animation, but I do not know how to solve problem with two different animations on the same object.

Edit 3. I find problem!

Comment: Can you please provide some code you have written so we can assist? I'm a bit confused by your question. I take it you have created the two keyframe animations in css. Now are you wanting to have two animations on the same button? If so, which one do you want to play first? One thing to consider, add the animation to a css class, and then add that class to the html element on the click event.

Comment: @Spangle two different animations in css and two different buttons. I do not want to two animation on the same button

Comment: Without knowing how your animations work, and seeing this is tagged [jquery], I'll assume you're using `.animate()` - how you handle it depends on what you want - if you want the 2nd animation to proceed after the first, then just use `.animate()` again.  Or use `.finish()` or `.stop(true, false)`  https://api.jquery.com/stop/#stop-clearQueue-jumpToEnd https://api.jquery.com/finish/ .  *If you're not using jquery .animate() then provide some code - that's why we ask.*

Comment: Please have a read through the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this meet your requirements?

```js
let btn_a = document.getElementById('a')
let btn_b = document.getElementById('b')
let btn_c = document.getElementById('c')
let div = document.getElementById('obj')
btn_a.addEventListener('click', function() {
  div.className = 'anim-a'
})
btn_b.addEventListener('click', function() {
  div.className = 'anim-b'
})
btn_c.addEventListener('click', function() {
  $('#obj').animate({}, function(){
    $('#obj').css({transform: 'rotate(30deg) translate(200px)'})
  })
})
```

```css
div {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}

.anim-a {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  width: 150px;
}

.anim-b {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='obj'>animated</div>
<button id='a'>anim-a</button>
<button id='b'>anim-b</button>
<button id='c'>anim-c</button>
```

**EDIT**

Without css fields, assuming that you're using jQuery, you can use `.animate()`. However, `.animate()` won't take `transform` as its property. We'll do this in the callback.

```
btn_c.addEventListener('click',function() {
  $('#obj').animate({}, function(){
    $('#obj').css({transform: 'rotate(30deg)'})
  })
})
```

Comment: Can I use transform such as rotate, translate without the field ".anim-a" and "anim-b"?

Comment: thank you! I see, that this result does not want to work with SVG object, but I hope that I find a solution.